# fish shell outputs ⏎ (i.e. an "abandon line") during startup on smaller terminal sizes

Tags: terminal, fish

Whenever I open a new terminal window (that's <100 columns wide) Fish prompts me with:

```
⏎
foo@bar ~>
```

I'm not expecting that first line with <kbd>⏎</kbd> to appear!  If it's 100 columns or wider, then this line doesn't appear...

I can't remember when this started happening, maybe a month or so, but I can say it certainly behaves this way with fish version 3.2.1 and whenever `$COLUMNS <= 99`.  I've emptied out my startup scripts trying to figure out what was causing it, and my MWE is a `config.fish` containing:

```
set foo (ls)
```

i.e. an external program whose complete output is captured.  I don't see that character when `$COLUMNS` is 100 or greater.

This feels like a bug, and I've searched here, the main stackoverflow site, and the issues on the fish github repository.  I'm using wayland under archlinux, showing in the [foot terminal emulator](https://codeberg.org/dnkl/foot) with Sway as a window manager.  I can replicate it in `weston-terminal` and `urxvt`, but I don't see this behaviour under `tmux`.

Suggestions about how to make this go away would be appreciated!

Comment: That's fish's way of telling you that it output something with no trailing newline: demo `printf hello`. There might be something in your `fish_greeting` function _or_ variable

Comment: @glennjackman yup, am aware where it comes from.  if I `set -U fish_greeting foo` then I see `foo` after the trailing newline indicator.  if I clear out my config (i.e. `mv ~/.config/fish /tmp`) then it stops showing that indicator, if I put the above MWE into the newly autocreated `~/.config/fish` then the indicator comes back

Comment: How did you install fish? My next step would be looking through all the [initialization files](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization-files)

Comment: I installed via Arch's package manager (`pacman`).  any suggestions about what to look for in the initialization files?  or do you think breaking out the debugger might be easier?  I was hoping that cleaning out the config in my home directory would be enough, I haven't modified `/etc/fish` or `/usr/share/fish` on this machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, though I don't think anyone worked out why it started appearing. It's fixed in https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7893.

Comment: building a copy of fish with the above mentioned code solves the issue for me, hopefully 3.2.2 will come out soon!